# Initialize static vector by template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, vector, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

How can I initialize the static member vector in the following class from its template arguments? In other words, I would like to insert all the template arguments into `my_vector_` before `main()` function. The order of arguments should be kept in the vector as well.

```
template <int... args>
class MyClass {
 public:
  MyClass();

 private:
  static vector<int> my_vector_;
}
```

Comment: do you want to initialize the vector as default?

Comment: `std::array` wouldn't be a better idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply expand the parameter list into an initializer list.

```
my_vector_ {args...};
```

However, are you sure you really want to do this? Unless you're going to add / remove items at run-time, you won't need dynamic storage and could equally well use a `std::array`.

Note, however, that you may not initialize a `static` data member of non-literal type inside a `class` definition. If you only have a single compilation unit (because the `template` is defined in a source file), you can do this.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <int... Args>
struct example
{
  // inline declaration
  static const std::array<int, sizeof...(Args)> numbers;   
};

// outline definition and initialization
template <int... Args>
const std::array<int, sizeof...(Args)> example<Args...>::numbers = {{Args...}};

int
main()
{
  std::cout << example<14, 92>::numbers[0] << std::endl;
}
```

<del>If the `template` is to be made available to more than one translation unit (and therefore provided in a header file) this becomes cumbersome, however. In this case, I recommend you use a function instead.</del>

Another option is to use a function instead. This is even more useful for non-`template` `class`es where putting the definition into the header file as shown above would cause a violation of the *one definition rule* (ODR).

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <int... Args>
struct example
{

  static const std::array<int, sizeof...(Args)>&
  numbers() noexcept
  {
    static const std::array<int, sizeof...(Args)> thenumbers = {{Args...}};
    return thenumbers;
  }

};

int
main()
{
  std::cout << example<14, 92>::numbers()[0] << std::endl;
}
```

Actually, I recommend that you do this anyway because I find it simpler even when ODR violations are not an issue.

Comment: I would have several instances of MyClass and I am sure I will access the vector every time. Therefore, I don't want to create and fill that vector every time.

Comment: I agree that std::array is better in my case.

Comment: @Fake A `static` variable will be fine for that. I was just picking about the “before `main`” part.

Comment: @Fake My original code snippet actually wouldn't compile. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Seems I have to change it to "thenumbers = {{Args...}}" in order to avoid any warning.

Comment: @Fake Yes, that's better. I have updated the answer. GCC doesn't warn about this but Clang does. I remember that once, GCC did as well. I don't really understand why this changed. But from my understanding, it's an aggregate initialization and double braces should be correct.

Comment: About the header vs. single compilation unit ... I think that's not true. This is a template, therefore defining everything in a header is fine, even if you include it in multiple compilation units.